# How to format a string in XAML without changing viewmodel's property getter?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have in my application the following interface:

```
public interface IContactMedium
{
    string ContactString { get; set; }
    string Type { get; set;}
    bool IsValid();
}
```

This interface is for objects that represent some sort of contact for a person. It could be a phone, email, etc. The `ContactString` property is the actual contact data (for a phone, for example, it would be the phone number), and the `Type` is for differentiation in case a person has more than one (for phone, a person can have a Home phone, a Work phone, Cell phone, etc.) The `IsValid` method is a validation mechanism for each different type of contact medium.

so, let's say I have two objects in my application - `Email` and `Phone` - both implement the interface. I'm going to make in the application a `UserControl` that holds a UI that manages a list of such objects. So the viewmodel would look something like this:

```
public class ContactsCollectionViewModel<T> : ViewModelBase where T : class, IContactMedium
{
    private ObservableCollection<T> _itemsCollection;

    public ContactCollectionViewModel(ObservableCollection<T> items)
    {
        ItemsCollection = items;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<T> ItemsCollection
    {
        get { return _itemsCollection; }
        set
        {
            if (_itemsCollection != value)
            {
                _itemsCollection = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(() => ItemsCollection);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to add to the `IContactMedium` interface another property/method that provides proper formatting for the `ContactString` property when used in Binding in WPF. The idea is that the format in the text box bound to `ContactString` differs depending on the concrete object that is actually stored in the collection:

```
<TextBox x:Name="ContactString"
         Text="{Binding ContactString, StringFormat=???}" />
```

I searched online a solution for this and couldn't find anything. I saw people suggesting modifying the `ContactString` property so the getter returns a formatted value. So, for the `Phone` object, for example, the property would look like this:

```
public string ContactString
{
    get 
    {
        return string.Format("({0}) {1}-{2}", _contactString.Substring(0,3), _contactString.Substring(4,3), _contactString.Substring(7,3));
    }
    set {
        _contactString = value;
    }
}
```

However, this is not a good solution for me. The information is not only used by the UI. It is also sent to other parts of the application, including a database, that need the phone number in its raw form: ##########.

Is there a way to provide the XAML a formatter to use in the `StringFormat` attribute of the binding? Can the formatting be dictated by the object that implement the interface? If yes, what type does it need to be, and how can I make it accessible to the `Binding` in XAML?

Comment: Does the View have the ability to extract the original object's type out of the ` IContactMedium`? Or is it considered a factory pattern object where the consumer does not know the original object, just the interface?

Comment: The View includes an ItemsControl that is bound to the ObservableCollection<T>, so it does not know the actual object—just the interface. I want to add something to the interface (a property or a method) that will expose to the View the formatter, and I'm wondering if it's even possible.

Comment: If you can add something to the interface, why not add a new property called `DisplayContact` which figures out the proper string format. Then bind to `DisplayContact`. ??

Comment: I guess that would be a fairly easy solution. However, then I'll need to add validation to that property as well. Is there a way to have the `ContactString` validation affect the validation of `DiaplayContact`? I guess if that's simple enough then this would be the easiest solution. I'm just a little baffled from the fact that there is no intuitive solution to make my own custom formatter for `StringFromat`. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The thing is that each concrete class that implements the interface would have different formatting rules

> Can the formatting be dictated by the object that implement the interface?

The dilema is, whether to add the formating logic to your business objects (`IContactMedium` implementations) or to presentation layer.

if it is business logic, then yes, you should add the formatting code to your business object.

But most probably it is presentation logic. In that case, either create DataTemplate foreach implementation of the `IContactMedium`, or create converter. In the converter you can choose correct formatting based on the value type. If the output is just plain text, use converter. If its more that plain text, e.g formatted text, use datatemplates.

**TIP:** You can use unit tests to test if all implementations of `IContactMedium` have its DataTemplate or are covered by the converter.

Answer (score 4):

> Can the formatting be dictated by the object that implement the interface?

In Xaml one can provide data templates which are associated with a specific class.

Simply provide the structure in the template with a formatting on the binding to the target property as shown below:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type c:Ship}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name, StringFormat=Ship: {0}}"
                        Foreground="Red" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type c:Passage}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name, StringFormat=Passage: {0}}"
                        Foreground="Blue" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ListBox Name="myListBox"
             Height="300"
             Width="200"
             ItemsSource="{Binding OBSCollection}">
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

So for my collection where both class instances of `Ship` and `Passage` adhere to `ITreeEntity`:

```
 public ObservableCollection<ITreeEntity> OBSCollection ...
```

When bound creates a list where the binding has a specific string format as such:

[image]

*Note in setting up the data the ships were added first followed by the passages. Xaml is not ordering them in anyway.*

---

Need to list different types objects in one ListBox from a composite collection? See my answers here:

- [Composite Collection ListBox Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31684202/285795)
- [Basic example of Listbox & Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31709015/285795)

Answer (score 0):

You can use converters. Keep your property simple.

```
public string ContactString { get; set; }
```

Implement converter

```
class MyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
           object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        contactString = value as string;
        if(contactString == null)
        {
             throw new InvalidArgumentException();
        }

        return string.Format("({0}) {1}-{2}",
          contactString.Substring(0,3), contactString.Substring(4,3),
          contactString.Substring(7,3));
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
          object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Add it as resource

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MyConverter x:Key="MyConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Use it

```
<TextBox x:Name="ContactString"
     Text="{Binding ContactString, Converter{StaticResource MyConverter}}" />
```

Comment: Thanks. The thing is that each concrete class that implements the interface would have different formatting rules. Should each object just expose a property of type IValueConverter for its own specific formatting?

Answer (score -1):

You can simply override the `ToString()` method. By default, a `ListBox` will use the object's `ToString()` method as the display text for the item.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("({0}) {1}-{2}", _contactString.Substring(0,3), _contactString.Substring(4,3), _contactString.Substring(7,3));
}
```

This means you don't have to do anything fancy in the `ListBox`, like defining a `DataTemplate`, as the `ListBox` will pick up the formatted string automatically.

```
<ListBox Name="myListBox"
         Height="300"
         Width="200"
         ItemsSource="{Binding OBSCollection}"/>
```

Comment: I ended up advising this to him on a comment (then I deleted when I saw this response). I don't see why its downvoted.

Comment: Theres no reason to override tostring. First of all, its better to have this logic outside the class, which allows you to use different formats on different places. Second, if you needed to change the format (presentation logic), you would have to change the business object. Its violation of SRP. Third, if you needed to have the format in business object, its better to use virtual property called e.g. DisplayName and use DisplayMemberPath in Lbx. Its just so easy to address this in WPF, so theres no reason to override tostring. If you dont agree, upvote please

Comment: What of the object changes? How would you change lbx?