# Get checkbox item from listbox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I am developing WPF application. In which I am adding `CheckBoxes` to a `ListBox` in following way.

```
foreach (User ls in lst)
{
     AddContacts(ls, lstContactList);
}

private void AddContacts(User UserData, ListBox lstbox)
{
    try
    {
        var txtMsgConversation = new CheckBox()
        {

                Padding = new Thickness(1),
                IsEnabled = true,
                //IsReadOnly = true,
                Background = Brushes.Transparent,
                Foreground = Brushes.White,
                Width = 180,
                Height = 30,
                VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
                VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
                Content = UserData.Name, //+ "\n" + UserData.ContactNo,
                Margin = new Thickness(10, 10, 10, 10)
        };

        var SpConversation = new StackPanel() { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal };

        SpConversation.Children.Add(txtMsgConversation);

        var item = new ListBoxItem()
        {
                Content = SpConversation,
                Uid = UserData.Id.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                Background = Brushes.Black,
                Foreground = Brushes.White,
                BorderThickness = new Thickness(1),
                BorderBrush = Brushes.Gray
        };


        item.Tag = UserData;

        lstbox.Items.Add(item);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Need to log Exception
    }
}
```

Now I need to get the checked items from `ListBox`. How do I proceed here, I tried below code, which returning null,

```
CheckBox chkBox = lstContactList.SelectedItem as CheckBox;
```

Thoughts?

Comment: This is not the way you should use WPF. Read about `DataBinding` and `MVVM` or you make anything more complicated than required.

Comment: Delete all that and use proper XAML and DataBinding.

Comment: I managed to get using below code,     foreach (ListBoxItem item in lstContactList.Items)
           {
               var stackPanel = item.Content as StackPanel;
               var checkBox = stackPanel.Children[0] as CheckBox;

Comment: When creating your text box, add an event handler to its checked changed event. In that handler the sender will cast to a checkbox and you can use that to manage a collection of checked items. This is a pointer not an answer because mvvm will make this far simpler and you look at that. Code behind can be faster to prove an idea but in your case - go straight for mvvm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way of creating dynamic multiple items in a listbox is not in codebehind, but to create a template for the items, and then bind it to a list of items.

**Example**

Say I have a bunch of passages `List<Passage> Passages { get; set; }`:

```
public class Passage
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

In my xaml I create a template and bind to it

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Passages}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name, StringFormat=Passage: {0}}"
                           Foreground="Blue" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The result looks like this for my four passages "Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma" and "I-25":

[image]

Then if I want the selected item, such as the recently checked `Beta` above, I just enumerate my List for the selected one(s).

```
 var selecteds = Passages.Where(ps => ps.IsSelected == true);
```

---

Need to list different types objects in one ListBox? Say from binding to a  composite collection or an `ObservableCollection<T>`?

See my answers here:

- [Composite Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31684202/285795)
- [ObservableCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31666724/285795)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response, it helped me find an answer to my problem. The only detail I would add is to use 'Window.DataContext' to bind the results to the List.

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
</Window.DataContext>
```